# Replacing the active class for li using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview

when i click on  the treeview other treeviews needs to be closed, tried allot but couldn't solve it can anybody help me please.

http://7revolution.com/captain/captain/empty.html

```js
$('.sidebar-menu .treeview').on('click', function(){
            if($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $('.sidebar-menu').find('.treeview .treeview-menu').removeClass('active');
    $(this).find(".treeview.active").removeClass("active");
    e.preventDefault();
            }
            else{
    $('.sidebar-menu').find('.treeview-menu').attr('display', 'block');
                }
```

```html
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="index.html">
                                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/widgets.html">
                                <i class="fa fa-th"></i> <span>Widgets</span> <small class="badge pull-right bg-green">new</small>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
                                <span>Charts</span>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                <li><a href="pages/charts/morris.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Morris</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/charts/flot.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Flot</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/charts/inline.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Inline charts</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>
                                <span>UI Elements</span>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                <li><a href="pages/UI/general.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> General</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/UI/icons.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Icons</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/UI/buttons.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Buttons</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/UI/sliders.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Sliders</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/UI/timeline.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Timeline</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

When i click on  the treeview other treeviews needs to be closed, tried allot but couldn't solve it can anybody help me please.
when i click on  the treeview other treeviews needs to be closed, tried allot but couldn't solve it can anybody help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Javascript:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $('.sidebar-menu .treeview').on('click', function () {
    $('.treeview').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');  
  });
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
    .sidebar-menu .treeview-menu{ display: none; }
    .active .treeview-menu {
         display: block;
     }

     .treeview-menu {
         display: none;
     }
</style>
```

Comment: once please check the following link, sorry for the late reply.
http://7revolution.com/captain/captain/empty.html

Comment: This forum is not to provide such type of support. I posted the answer for the problem you posted.

Comment: thanks for this solution, but it dint get solved. expected the solution. unfortunately i dint get. even though am happy

Comment: :) Ok, I am doing that for you. Don't loose hope.

Comment: Replace content of your js/captain/app.js with the javascript provided in http://jsfiddle.net/3u6L2130/

Comment: hey am really happy Apul Gupta.... from that day to today i was searching the new plugin, i tried tried and loss the  hope. thanks. am feeling happy. i lost the hope on stackoverflow, and left it aside, but i opened it for once and i got the solution.. thanks sooooooo much.

Comment: You are welcomed. I know you were hopeless that's why did for you. :)

Comment: thanks. i just removed a line in your submitted code, line no. 593
will it disturb the code ? the following is that line 
" isActive = $(this).hasClass('active'); "

Answer (score 0):

This might help out a little: http://jsfiddle.net/qh8vz4y4/

JS

```
$('.sidebar-menu .treeview').on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.treeview').not(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

CSS

```
.active .treeview-menu {
    display: block;
}
.treeview-menu {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: tried this one, not working. please check the following link

http://7revolution.com/captain/captain/empty.html